# Is there a way to suspend a unix job running in the background?

Tags: unix

Is there a way to suspend, and then later (after logging in and out) restart a unix job running in the background on a remote computer?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `kill -STOP` and `kill -CONT`, but you can't reconnect to its pty.  What you really want is [`screen`](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) or [`tmux`](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/).